# Why onchange fires before onclick in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, events

I would still take advantage of the expertise and availability of this community.
My question is: why if we have a code similar to

```
<input name="" type="checkbox"  onClick="first()" onChange="second()">
<script type="text/javascript">
function first(){
    console.log('first')
    }
function second(){
    console.log('second')
    }
</script>
```

in firefox onclick event fires before onchange while in chrome happens the opposite?
Thanks for your answers, maybe i have not explained in the best way
I know that using onMuseDown the problem is solved but i want to understand the reason for such behavior in Chrome with the onchange and onclick event

Comment: Why do you want to use them both? I prefer onClick on checkbox for cross browser consistency. The order depens on browser implementation see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575338/what-the-difference-between-click-and-change-on-a-checkbox

Comment: Chrome will simply fire the event in the order it encountered it, doing `onChange="second()" onClick="first()"` will reverse it.

Comment: @KyleNeedham: thank you for the answer but also if i reverse the events in my chrome version the result is still the same

Answer (score 1):

Because `onChange` is triggered due to `onClick`

Answer (score 1):

One dirty solution might be to use `onMouseDown` instead of `onClick`.

But I'm also wondering why you really need both ;)

Comment: I know that with onMouseDown the code works, but i want to understand the reason this behavior, thanks for the answer.